# GM12-15BY-100 Stepper motor damaged,what caused it?

Tags: dc-motor, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I have a dc stepper motor, GM12-15BYC:

2-phase,
unload typical current = 150mA,
Pull-out rate:800Hz,
Pull-out torque:120

I am using the driver [DRV8834](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8834.pdf) to control it.

The configuration of the driver is:

MicroStep per step: 4
Step/Dir(Indexer) mode
xVref = 55.7mV,so the Itrip = 111mA.

First I managed to make the motor moving, however after playing around for sometime, the motor stopped moving, and seems died. I changed to another motor, the same thing happened again.

So for testing what is the problem, I applied a 10Hz frequency to the motor, then:

If I don't plug the motor in, then I can see the 4 windings all have signals of the correct frequency that I applied to it.

If I do plug the motor in:

1. The motor is not moving;
2. Checked the 4 wings, one of which phase has pulses, while another of the phase does not. For example, Black&Yellow is a pair, Red &White is a pair, I can see waves in Black and Red, but not in Yellow and White.
3. However, the frequency of the wave is changed significantly, now every pulse is 25 mircroSecond. while previously was about 1.5 second.

I thought this definitely indicates that there is something wrong with the motor.

So I checked the motor with multimeter, and find: 
1. the resistance for each phase is correct. 30 Ohm.
2. no short or open circuit within each phase or between two phases.

My question is :

1. What might be the problem with this motor?
2. What might cause this damage of the motor?

Many thanks!

Comment: You may be seeing the behavior of a chopping current regulator turning the winding on and off rapidly to achieve an effective average of the set point - see the DR8834 documentation. It's unclear if your new motor worked before also failing, or if it never worked indicating the setup may have failed. Given your motor is quite low current be sure you have the chopper set to deliver the proper current and that the sense resistor (if external) is correct.  If the fast pulses you are seeing are chopping, they *should* change to the other winding when the controller is stepped to the next position.

Comment: Are the motors definitely being damaged - or do they work again after a while?
It MAY be that you are thermally overloading the driver IC and that it is going into a thermal shut down mode while it cools.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Hi. Thanks for replying. Tbh I am not sure if motors are damaged, since I measured them use multimeter but they seems fine. (the resistances is correct as in the datasheet). They don't work again, not even after a while. Unfortunately I don't have another setup to test the motor. Is there any other ways to test the motor?  The driver IC generates correct signals when motor is unplugged though... so when the motor is on the driver is thermally overloaded?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for replying. For the chopping current I set it up to around 111mA, while the typical unload current for the motor at 1000Hz pulse is 150mA. I am using an sense resistor of 0.1 Ohm and reference voltage of about 55mV.  I couldn't find the maximum current of this motor because it's not included in the datasheet. Do you think this set-up is making sense, or maybe the chopping current is too low to drive the motor?